# Being Removed My Custom Settings When Closed The Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I save in runtime some values to a custom settings file that I created manually in windows form application.

Here is a code piece;

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listvSections.Items)
{
    if (!Definitons.Default.Context.ContainsKey(item.Text))
    {
        Definitons.Default.Context.Add(item.Text, item.SubItems[1].Text); 
    }
}

Definitons.Default.Save();
```

As you may recognize, Definitons is the my custom settings file that I created it manually. But I want to write key and values to it in runtime. After I closed the form and stopped the debugging process, I see nothing written in this file.

Is that possible writing in a settings file permanently not only in runtime?

Comment: What exactly is `Definitions`? It could help to see its code.

Comment: It's just a .settings file. Definitions.settings

Comment: be sure that you have at least 1 setting set-up at design time and only the `user setting` is able to be modified and saved at runtime.

Comment: I think it's not allowed to add a setting in runtime.